# Correct way to write the set theoretic definition of a relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I want to write the set theoretic definition of a relation $\preceq$ on a set $X$. So I thought I need to write that we have either $a \preceq b$ or $a \not\preceq b$. However writing $\forall a,b: (a \preceq b) \vee \neg(a \preceq b)$ won't do the job I believe since we have that $P \vee \neg P$ is always true even if we have not defined the value (True of False) of $P$.

So what is the correct way to write it?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You have to write "either $a\preceq b$ or $a\npreceq b$". That is also an always true statement.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes that is exactly the difficulity I have. I try to formally define a binary relation. Here the binary relation has the same meaning as a binary relation in a partial order, exepted that a partial order has to be reflexive, anti-symmetric, and transitivite.

Comment: No, but you say that you are trying to formalize a statement which is always true; why are you surprised that you end up with a sentence which is always true?

Comment: I didn't meant to say that, I meant to write the definition of a relation. As I could say it, a relation is a function $f: X^2 \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. But I don't want to write it this way.

Comment: A relation is a set $R$ that for some set $X$, $R\subseteq X\times X$. Period. Partial orders are relations such that bla bla bla.

Comment: To expand, for $R\subseteq X\times X$, we say $a\sim b\Leftrightarrow (a,b)\in R$.  Note that we do not require that $a\sim b\Rightarrow b\sim a$ for the general concept of relations.  If it happens to satisfy that additional constraint for all $a,b\in X$, it is *symmetric*.  Similarly there are other terms used to classify relations (reflexive, transitive, total, anti-symmetric, ...).

Comment: @AsafKaragila (or @JMoravitz) Can you please expand that to an answer to get it form the unanswered list? Since it was helpful I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We define a **relation**, $R$, on a set $X$, as a subset of the Cartesian product $X\times X$.  That is to say, $R\subseteq X\times X$.

We say that $a$ is *related* to $b$, written as $a~ R~ b$ whenever $(a,b)\in R$.

Note that this definition does not require any additional properties of our relation.  Given additional specific properties, we can define such things as *partial orders* and *equivalence relations*.

---

Common classifications of relations:

- A relation $R$ is *reflexive* if for all $a\in X$ you have $a~R~ a$
- A relation $R$ is *symmetric* if for all $(a,b)\in R$, you also have $(b,a)\in R$
- A relation $R$ is *anti-symmetric* if for all $(a,b)\in R$ with $a\neq b$, you have $(b,a)\not\in R$.  (equivalently worded as if $a~R~b$ and $b~R~a$ then $a=b$)
- A relation $R$ is *transitive* if for all $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c)\in R$, you also have $(a,c)\in R$.

---

Useful types of relations:

- An *equivalence relation* is one which is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.  The prototypical example is $=$.
- A *partial order* is a relation which is reflexive, anti-symmetric and transitive.  Note, that with a partial order, we do not require that every pair be comparable.
- A *total order* is a relation which is reflexive, anti-symmetric, transitive, and has the property that you always have either $a~R~b$ or you have $b~R~a$.  The prototypical example is $\leq$.